# Can I use a DataSet as my Entity?

Tags: jackson

Can someone point me to a good explanation of the criteria a class must meet to use the default deserializaton for Jackson?

I can do a post and supply a HashMap collection of string/jsonObjects, but it won't work with a dataset that contains the same information in a row.  I tried implementing my own Deserializer but the response is always "Unprocessable Entity".  I have been successful using specific classes, but I am trying to generalize my solution by passing a dataset.

Obviously I need a better understanding of what is happening!  TIA!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on rough type of your class. Jackson has specialized handling for:

- Arrays of types
- `Collection` implementations
- `Map` implementations
- `Enum`s
- Other

If type is none of first 4 categories, it will be considered "Other", and expected to follow Java Bean convention of either public fields, or getters and/or setters.
There also has to be a no-argument constructor (need not be public), or another constructor annotated with `@JsonCreator` -- expect that some public single-argument constructors (`String`, `int`/`Integer`, `long`/`Long`, `boolean`/`Boolean`) are also accepted when binding from JSON Scalar values.

But to get more information you really should share the actual exception you get: above is just the general idea of what is needed. Jackson can work with all kinds of classes, and is not particularly strict in how classes are defined. But it does have expectations on how various JSON Structures match with POJOs.